# NestJS - No metadata for "EmployeeRepository" was found with authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, typeorm

I try to do some authentication for my nestjs app but I got stuck with this error and I don't know where to look at

My app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AgenciesModule,
    ActionsModule,
    AuthModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: '************',
      username: '*********',
      password: '*********',
      database: '*********',
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
    EmployeesModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My auth.service.ts

```
import { EmployeeRepository } from 'src/employees/entities/employee.repository';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(EmployeeRepository)
    private employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.employeeRepository.findOne({
      where: { email, password },
    });
    // this work with postman if I put false data
    //const user = {
    // email: "email",
    // password: "password",
    //}
    if (user && user.email === email && user.password === password) {
      const { password, ...result } = user;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

My auth.controller.ts

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('login')
  async login(@Body() body) {
    return this.authService.login(body.email, body.password);
  }
}
```

My auth.module.ts

```
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([EmployeeRepository])],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And my employee.repository.ts

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Employee } from './employee.entity';

@EntityRepository(Employee)
export class EmployeeRepository extends Repository<Employee> {}
```

I didn't put the different import for each file but I can provide them if needed

I checked all the file name and path from the differents import and they are all correct and I also updated my packages just in case.

These posts dosen't help :
[NestJS - No metadata for "<Entity>" was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73142949/nestjs-no-metadata-for-entity-was-found)
[No metadata for "User" was found using TypeOrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562162/no-metadata-for-user-was-found-using-typeorm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in auth.module.ts

```
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([EmployeeRepository])]
```

Change like this

```
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Employee])]
```